# How to run many users calls from one Thread Group at the exactly the same time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

Im just begining with stress tests in Jmeter and have following problem. I want to call 50 times at once (50 users) for one endpoint [ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqf7H.png). When I just leave empty "Ramp-up period" these calls have very small delay but still have - intention is to calls it at exactly the same time [ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G0rp.png)

Comment: IMHO there will be always some small delay since network communication is serial at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want the request to be sent at exactly the same moment with 50 users - add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) and set the number of simulated users to group by to 50 (or whatever it the number of threads in your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group))

[image]

More information: [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)